# Argument count limit of methods in Smalltalk-80 implementation

Tags: oop, smalltalk

The maximum number of arguments of a method is limited to `2^5-1`(i.e. 31) because there is only 5 bits to encode the number of arguments in a compiled method as illustrated in [Figure 27.4 of the blue book](http://www.mirandabanda.org/bluebook/bluebook_chapter27.html#CompiledMethods27). But the double extended send bytecode has 8 bits to encode the number of arguments (see the definition of `doubleExtendedSendBytecode` [here](http://www.mirandabanda.org/bluebook/bluebook_chapter28.html#SendBytecodes28)), which means I can send as many as `2^8-1` (i.e. 127) arguments to a message (using `perform:` or the statement will not be compiled). Is this a contradiction? I think the bytecode uses too many bits to encode the number of arguments.

Comment: Why do you need so many args?

Comment: But why does the implementation support it in the first place?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, this is a contradiction but it did not yet matter enough.

Also, the number of arguments in a methods is bounded to the maximum number of temporary variables in a method, too, which in most Smalltalks happen to be `2^8-1`.

There is another part to that:

In Squeak, the number of arguments is actually restricted to 15 (`2^4-1`), and also has only a nibble (4 bit) of space in the method header.
As the comment of Squeak's `CompiledMethod` states:

```
(index 18)  6 bits: number of temporary variables (#numTemps)
(index 24)  4 bits: number of arguments to the method (#numArgs)
```

with the `#numTemps` *including* the number of arguments, too.

Long story short, yes, **the `doubleExtendedSendBytecode` could encode more arguments than actually expressible in a `CompiledMethod`**.

This is one of the reasons it was replaced in Squeak by the `doubleExtendedDoAnything` bytecode that can do more than just sends, but limits the number of arguments to `2^5-1` (which is *still* more than the `CompiledMethod` can encode, but it is not unlikely that `CompiledMethod` will change in the foreseeable future to encode more than 15 arguments).

Answer (score 1):

The actual number of arguments used is mostly small. The number of arguments of CompiledMethods in a Moose 4.6 Image I have here:

```
|bag|
bag := IdentityBag new.
CompiledMethod allInstances do:[ :element | bag add: element numArgs ].
bag sortedCounts

52006 -> 0
25202 -> 1
6309  -> 2
2133  -> 3
840   -> 4
391   -> 5
191   -> 6
104   -> 7
61    -> 8
12    -> 9
11    -> 10
5     -> 11
4     -> 12
3     -> 13
2     -> 15
1     -> 14
```